# communication between jquery and aspx page

Tags: jquery

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Send your proposal": function() {
                var ID=this.id;
                //alert(ID);



$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9020/Alternate.aspx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //data: 'title='+$('#farfalla-addalt').val(),
    //dataType: "json",
   data:"newtext",
    success: function () {
        alert('ajax file called');
    }
});
```

the problem I am facing here is that I am not knowing the id of the textbox from where I am fetching the text 
and I am unaware of the significance of each of these attributes of .ajax() function
whether to write the full path or just page name
what is content type for what shoul i write against it
what is data carrying
will it post **newtext** on the page
the thing is that the function is running as alert message is dispalyed

Answer (score 0):

If you know the class of the textbox that you are looking for, then you can use the jquery selector:

```
$('input .className').val();
```

But this will only work correctly if the textbox is the only input on the page with the given class. If it is not then you could attempt to wrap the area where the textbox is dropped with a container div that has an id, as such:

```
<div id='divTextboxDrop'>
    //Textbox will be dropped here
</div>
```

And then you could do something like this

```
$('#divTextboxDrop input:first').val();
```

It is really contingent upon how much control you have over the injection.

As far as the ajax functionality that you are having difficulty with, I would say look at the jquery ajax specifications that can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As per this page the following are some of the attribute values of the ajax function

url - The target url of the page that the ajax call will be targeting
contentType - The format of the content you are posting. So long as you are doing a standard http call then you don't even need to specify this from my understanding. However, if you are posting JSON, then yes this requires a change. 
data - The actual data that is being sent along. If, as it looks like in your case, you are posting JSON then the value here should be your stringified JSON object.
success - Function to call if the ajax call succeeds

Hope this helps

Comment: there is no compulsion that the web page where this dislog box is popping is an aspx page

the textbox is a javascript originated textbox
with only class attribute

Comment: My apologies, must have gotten this question confused with another one I had open. 1 second while I edit to reflect this.

Comment: I am using this just to check it is posting or not 
Am i  correct
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.aspx",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
success is shown by the alert but the text is never posted

Comment: Well there will not be any data returned unless the .aspx page you are targeting returns it. I would recommend making a small web method and posting to that. You can specify exactly what you want returned in that case, and all you have to do is target the .aspx page that contains the method and append the method name after it ("myPage.aspx/myMethodName"). Here is some simple instruction on how to accomplish this:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I dont want anything to be returned but to be posetd on to teh web page

Comment: If you need anything to be posted to the page you are currently on then you need to call a function that returns something. Lets say you want to asynchronously get the date from a web service and then put it on your current page. You would have a web method that returns the date and you would call it using jquery.ajax. You would then use your success function to place it on the page. Something like success: function(data) { $('#someDiv').append("<li>" + data + "</li>"); }

Comment: if in the data attribute I write this
data:"newtext",
what about this will it get posted onto the aspx page I had written nothing on the web page earlier and no function has been defined

Comment: No. Nothing will be posted. If the target of the ajax call does not return anything, then you will not get any data back. "newtext" is given to the ajax target as a variable, the target does nothing with it, and then the target returns nothing back.

Comment: but I dont want anything to be returned
cant it simply be posted ?

Comment: Yes, it can. Don't expect anything to come back in "data" if you don't return anything.

Comment: but it is not happening that is why I am crying

Comment: I think you need to have a better understanding of what it is that you are actually doing. Read up on what AJAX really is and if you want further instruction from me then write out exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: i am testing something as to what i am writing here can it post the text written in the data attribute onto the aspx page or not
the trivia is that the success function is working so dont know where the problem lies as the text is not being posted

Comment: You're posting to a .aspx page. How are you expecting this call to be handled? If this is your approach I doubt you are doing anything with the data you are posting to the page. Put a break-point in visual studio in the earliest page lifecycle method in the .aspx page you're posting to and look at what you're actually doing. I'll say it one last time: you need to post to a web method.